# Sideways table appendix header not sideways

Tags: rotating, appendix, sidewaystable, sidewaysfigure, sidewaysfigurepage

I have included a table (a graphic of a table) in my appendix. I want it to be sideways and I am able to flip it. The problem is that the appendix header "Appendix B ..." does not flip sideways and it put on a separate page in front of the flipped table.

I use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\emergencystretch 3em
\usepackage{packages}
\usepackage{appendix}
\newcommand{\addappendix}{   % Self-created command to insert appendix with predefined settings
    \newpage
    \appendix
    \section*{Appendix}   % Name of appendix
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix}  % Add appendix name to table of contents
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}    % Change numbering of section to upper-case letters

\begin{document}

\section{Bergsikringsklasser og sikringsmengder i tunnel} 

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \captionof{table}[Caption]{Caption}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Images/N-V521/bergsikringsklasser_tunnel.png}
    \label{tab:vedlegg_bergsikringsklasser_tunnel}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: The title of the appendix]

[image: The appendix itself]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question just 2 minutes after I asked this question:

I just moved the `\begin{landscape}` above the `\section`